# How extend beamertemplate{background}?

Tags: beamer

I am writing a custom beamer theme. In one of my theme `.sty` files I am using:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
    \fill[color=greenCiti] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,0.75);
    \node at (0.7,9.2) {\includegraphics{logo-citi-small.png}};
    \node at (1.0,0.375) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{logo-univ.png}};
    \node at (3.5,0.375) {\includegraphics[width=3.2cm]{logo-ra.png}};
    \node at (11.6,0.36) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo-insa.png}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Now I need to extend this property, in order to add a fourth image in the top right corner of my slides but only for one document using the theme and thus not in the theme file itself.

I.e I want to add a fourth line such as:

```
\node at (6.6,5.2) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{fig/logo-bull.png}};
```

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\setbeamertemplate{background}...}` in the document itself. Here I have used a background picture.

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
    \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,opacity=0.4] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background1}};
}
```

Replace the contents of `setbeamertemplate` above with relevant code for the background and replace the theme in the below code with yours.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
\date[ISPN ’80]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers}
\author[Euclid]{Euclid of Alexandria \texttt{euclid@alexandria.edu}}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
    \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,opacity=0.4] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background1}};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{First section}
\subsection{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
\framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
\begin{theorem}
There is no largest prime number. \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but what I need is a way to add a picture on top of the existing background and not to replace it

Comment: @ManuelSelva This did not replace any thing. If you show your code for `\setbeamertemplate{background}{`, it will be easy for answering specifically. Can you please add it to the question?

Comment: Sorry for vague question, I updated it

Comment: did you saw my question's update ?